# what is the difference between windows csv and mac csv?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file using this code

```
if (($handle = fopen($csvFilePath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $c=0;
        $string="";
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($c>0)
        {
        if(($data[$email]!="") and ($data[$firstname]!="") and ($data[$lastname]!=""))
        {
        $string.='(1,';         
            $string.="'".$data[$email]."',";
            $string.="'".$data[$firstname]."',";
            $string.="'".$data[$lastname]."',";
            $string.="'".Yii::app()->params['clientimporttext']."'";

       $string.='),';
       }
        }
        $c++;
    }
fclose($handle);

}
```

It is working fine with windows csv. 
but when i create a csv from mac and parse that it is not working.( it cant identify end of line),

also when i open the same windows csv with mac and parse using the same code it is not working. 
 but when i save it as windows csv. it again works.

**so actually wat is the difference between mac csv and windows csv?

Is the delimiter different for these two? 

How should i change the code to make it work with both?**

Comment: Difference is the line ending characters.... Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

Comment: Look into `auto_detect_line_endings`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is in the PHP doc comments:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the **auto_detect_line_endings** run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

The problem is in the difference between line endings on Windows and unix-like machines (as your mac is):   `windows ='\r\n'` and  `unix = '\n'`

The solution: add this line before opening the file:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return characters in Windows are `\r` in Mac I believe its `\r\n`.

Comment: It's `\r\n` on windows, `\n` on unix and is (was?) `\r` on mac

Answer (score 0):

Mac and Windows use different EOL characters.  That gets confusing on the best of days.
Here is a good explanation of how they work on different platforms:
http://peterbenjamin.com/seminars/crossplatform/texteol.html